# build the interpolation polynomial of degree higher than n-1

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

I know that degree of the interpolation polynomial with n nodes cannot be more than n-1.
I am asking about THE unique interpolation polynomial, what is the reason for it to have degree at-most-n-1 and not n.
Can I build the interpolation polynomial of degree higher than n-1 for n points?

Comment: You say **the** interpolation polynomial, implying only one.  There is only one line passing through two points.  There are infinitely many parabolas passing through two points however.  Similarly, there are infinitely many polynomials of degree $n$ or greater passing through $n$ points (*who all have different $x$ coordinates*).  Can we talk about one or more of these?  Absolutely.  Can we claim it is the unique result?  No.

Comment: @JMoravitz So you're saying that there is only one interpolation polynomial with the degree at most n-1, and infinite polynomials (but not interpolation polynomials) of degree n? Is this correct?

Comment: If you define any polynomial passing through the desired collection of points to be "*an* interpolation polynomial" then all of those are interpolation polynomials as well.  The issue is if you want to talk about *the* interpolation polynomial which implies that it must be uniquely defined in which case the polynomials of degree $n$ you refer to could not be candidates for "the" interpolation polynomial despite passing through the desired points since there would be no way to uniquely determine it.

Comment: @JMoravitz The question is, can THE interpolation polynomial (unique one) have the degree more than n-1 (n in our case)? The answer is no, though those polynomials exist, just not the interpolation ones. I want to know why. i thought that is somehow connected with derivatives? Hopefully, you understand my question, not a native speaker, sorry...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there some intuition for Lagrange interpolation formula?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81044/is-there-some-intuition-for-lagrange-interpolation-formula)

Comment: @JMoravitz I don't think that's it. I edited the question, maybe now it sounds right.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606499/finding-an-interpolation-polynomial-of-degree-greater-than-n1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpolation polynomials can have higher degree. But then we cannot any longer talk about **the** interpolation polynomial. There is only one polynomial of degree at-most-$(n-1)$ going through any given set of $n$ points, but there are infinitely many degree-$n$ polynomials, and even more on higher degrees (for certain notions of "more").

For instance, given two points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, *the* interpolation polynomial $x$ is a straight line between the points. If we go up to second degree, however, we have loads of other options, such as $x^2$, or $-3x^2+4x$, and so on.

Comment: I understand that, but I want to know why THE interpolation polynomial can have only at-most-(n-1) degree and not n?

Comment: @Valerie If you take the general degree-$(n-1)$ polynomial $$p(x)=a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\cdots +a_1x+a_0$$and you have $n$ points $(x_1,y_1),\cdots,(x_n,y_n)$, then you get $ n$ equations $$p(x_1)=y_1\\p(x_2)=y_2\\\vdots\\p(x_n)=y_n$$with $n$ unknowns $a_{n-1},a_{n-2},\cdots,a_0$. If all the $x_i$ are distinct, then this set of equations has a _single_ solution, giving the interpolation polynomial. If you allow $p$ to have higher degree, then you get more unknowns but not any more equations, giving you more solutions.